# Multiply char by integer (c++)

Tags: c++, string, char, multiplication

Is it possible to multiply a char by an int?

For example, I am trying to make a graph, with *'s for each time a number occurs.

So something like, but this doesn't work

```
char star = "*";
int num = 7;

cout << star * num //to output 7 stars
```

Comment: @dubya, the c++ tag is a lot more useful here than 'help'. For a start, we can assume you need help because, well, you're asking a question here :-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I wouldn't call that operation "multiplication", that's just confusing. Concatenation is a better word.

In any case, the C++ standard string class, named `std::string`, has a constructor that's perfect for you.

```
string ( size_t n, char c );
```

Content is initialized as a string formed by a repetition of character `c`, `n` times.

So you can go like this:

```
char star = '*';  
int num = 7;
std::cout << std::string(num, star) << std::endl;
```

Make sure to include the relevant header, `<string>`.

Comment: +1 for referencing the std library. Too few folks do that these days.

Comment: "Concatenation" is also a bad word.  There isn't really a word for this, but 'iteration' I think comes closer, since that's really what you have to do to achieve the desired result.

Comment: It was 'catenation' when I wrote it.

Comment: My dictionary says that one of the definitions of 'concatenation' is 'add by linking or joining so as to form a chain or series'.  That strikes me as being an accurate description of this operation.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concatenate and http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concatenate

Comment: -1 for needlessness. A for loop is, by definition, more readable than using the standard library.

Comment: "Multiplication" makes sense to me considering that multiplication is addition repeated a given number of times. In the same sense, repeating a char or string a given number of times to form a new string would make intuitive sense to be called multiplication of a char or a string by an (unsigned) integer.

Answer (score 8):

the way you're doing it will do a numeric multiplication of the binary representation of the `'*'` character against the number 7 and output the resulting number.

What you want to do (based on your c++ code comment) is this:

```
char star = '*';
int num = 7;
for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    cout << star;
}// outputs 7 stars.
```

Answer (score 8):

GMan's over-eningeering of this problem inspired me to do some template meta-programming to further over-engineer it.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int c, char ch>
class repeater {
  enum { Count = c, Char = ch };
  friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const repeater &r) {
    return os << (char)repeater::Char << repeater<repeater::Count-1,repeater::Char>();
  }
};

template<char ch>
class repeater<0, ch> {
  enum { Char = ch };
friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const repeater &r) {
    return os;
  }
};

main() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "8 r = " << repeater<8,'r'>() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ah, a meta-programming counter-part to me answer. Most excellent. +1 (Careful, you'll get down votes for being "too clever")

Comment: @GMan So using a built-in std::string constructor is less readable than a for-loop, but this deserves a +1 from you?

Comment: @josh: If you didn't ever see my answer, and the stupidity expressed by some users on this question (and hence my reply to that stupidity), this won't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
std::cout << std::string(7, '*');
```

Answer (score -1):

The statement should be:

```
char star = "*";
```

(star * num) will multiply the ASCII value of '*' with the value stored in num

To output '*' n times, follow the ideas poured in by others.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
//include iostream and string libraries

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    for (int Count = 1; Count <= 10; Count++)
    {
        cout << string(Count, '+') << endl;
    }

    for (int Count = 10; Count >= 0; Count--)
    {
        cout << string(Count, '+') << endl;
    }


return 0;
```

}