# Porting Perl to C++ `print "\x{2501}" x 12;`

Tags: c++, perl

I am porting a program from Perl to C++ as a learning objective. I arrived at a routine that draws a table with commands like the following:

```
Perl: print "\x{2501}" x 12;
```

And it draws 12 times a '━' ("box drawings heavy horizontal").

Now I figured out part of the problem already:

```
Perl: \x{}, \x00        Hexadecimal escape sequence;
C++:  \unnnn
```

To print a single Unicode character:

```
C++:  printf( "\u250f\n" );
```

But does C++ have a smart equivalent for the 'x' operator or would it come down to a for loop?

---

**UPDATE**
Let me include the full source code I am trying to compile with the proposed solution. The compiler does throw an errors:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror project.cpp -o project
project.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
project.cpp:38:3: error: ‘string’ is not a member of ‘std’
project.cpp:38:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘s’
project.cpp:39:3: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
project.cpp:39:16: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        if ( argc != 2 )   
        {
                fprintf( stderr , "usage: %s matrix\n", argv[0] );
                exit( 2 );
        } else {
                //std::string s(12, "\u250f" );
                std::string s(12, "u" );
                std::cout << s;
        }       
}
```

Comment: Related: [Multiply char by integer (c++)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2596953), [In C++, I thought you could do “string times 2” = stringstring?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5145792), [Multiplying a string by an int in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11843226)

Comment: C uses `printf`. In C++, we prefer `std::cout << `.

Answer (score 3):

No, C++ doesn't have the "x" operator, however you can create a string with character repetition:

```
std::string s(12, <any character>);
```

Then you can print it like below (the "printf" is inherited from C, it might be not good to use it in your assignment):

```
std::cout << s;
```

(Of course, you can use any number, not just 12)

**UPDATE** for your update above:

I can compile your code with only minor change ("u" replaced by 'u' because it must be a character). My compiler is GCC 4.6.2 for Windows XP (MINGW32 version). What OS/compiler do you use?

Comment: Or, more directly, `std::cout << std::string(12, '\u250f');`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll have to Google for cout vs printf too I guess.

Comment: @jippie: No, don't Google it. Read [a recommended book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648).

Comment: I'm getting an error message: `error: ‘string’ is not a member of ‘std’`, probably need to include an extra library but not sure which one (and I'm not allowed to Google according to @LightnessRacesinOrbit ;o) )
`

Comment: @jippie `#include <string>`

Comment: Yes, @rightfold that compiles. But now I cannot pass a 2 byte unicode character to std::string :(

Comment: Oh, two bytes. Indeed that gets a bit more tricky.

Comment: std::wstring?  std::wcout?